# How to add swiple gesture with 3 buttons in a xib?

Tags: objective-c

I have a table view where i m adding a cell for the content of the table view and i need to add swipeable gesture with 3 buttons in that that table cell.

Comment: are u using xib file to load cell ?

Answer (score 1):

u haven't provide enough info about how you are implementing the tableview cell but i assume that u are using the xib file and also i assume that u want to display the 3 button when table view cell is swiped ..

first of all u should subclass the table view cell in my example i named the cell class as `CustomTableCell`

in this cell's xib file i am adding the a `view` and 3 buttons, it is something look like below image

[image]

in the above image `swipeView` should be on top of content view and it holds your swipe gestures

for example in `CustomTableCell.h` file

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface CustomTableCell : UITableViewCell 
 + (id)createMenuCell;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *swipeView;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button3;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
 @property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL showButton;

 - (IBAction)buttonOneAction:(id)sender;

 - (IBAction)buttonTwoAction:(id)sender;

 - (IBAction)buttonThreeAction:(id)sender;

 @end
```

and in `CustomTableCell.m` file

```
 #import "CustomTableCell.h"

 @implementation CustomTableCell
 #define  MAX_LEFT 160  //set the how much view has to be move
 #define ANIMATION_DUR 0.3 

 + (id)createMenuCell
 {
     NSArray *xibElements = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" owner:nil options:nil];
    for(id item in xibElements)
    {
      if([item isKindOfClass:[CustomTableCell class]])
      {
         return (CustomTableCell *)item;
      }
   }
   return nil;
 }


 - (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
 {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if(self)
     {
        [self setUpGestures];
     }
     return self; 
 }

 - (void)awakeFromNib {
 // Initialization code
 _showButton = NO; //simple avoid unwanted swipes when showing the buttons
 [self setUpGestures];
 }

 - (void)setUpGestures{
   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeftGesture =    [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftGestureAction)]; //to open 
   swipeLeftGesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft; //set the direction to swipe
   [self.swipeView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeftGesture];


  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightGestureAction)]; //this is for closing 
  [self.swipeView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightGesture];
 }

 - (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
    // Configure the view for the selected state
 }

 //button actions
 - (IBAction)buttonOneAction:(id)sender {
     NSLog(@"button one action");
 }

 - (IBAction)buttonTwoAction:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"button two action");

 }

 - (IBAction)buttonThreeAction:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"button three action");
 }

 //hear u are showing the buttons with left swipe 
 - (void)swipeLeftGestureAction
 {
    if(!_showButton)
    {
       CGRect destRect = self.swipeView.frame;
       destRect.origin.x = -MAX_LEFT;
       [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DUR animations:^{
        self.swipeView.frame = destRect;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
          _showButton = YES;
        }];
   }
 }

 //hear u are hiding the buttons if it is shown 
 - (void)swipeRightGestureAction
 {
    if(_showButton)
    {
       CGRect destRect = self.swipeView.frame;
       destRect.origin.x = 0;
       [UIView animateWithDuration:ANIMATION_DUR animations:^{
           self.swipeView.frame = destRect;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
           _showButton = NO;
        }];
     }
 }
```

**Note:** above is just i assumed so final result will be like below

[image]